# Filtering JS array of objects based on tags

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    company: "Photosnap",
    logo: "./images/photosnap.svg",
    new: true,
    featured: true,
    position: "Senior Frontend Developer",
    role: "Frontend",
    level: "Senior",
    postedAt: "1d ago",
    contract: "Full Time",
    location: "USA Only",
    languages: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    company: "Manage",
    logo: "./images/manage.svg",
    new: true,
    featured: true,
    position: "Fullstack Developer",
    role: "Fullstack",
    level: "Midweight",
    postedAt: "1d ago",
    contract: "Part Time",
    location: "Remote",
    languages: ["Python"],
    tools: ["React"]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    company: "Account",
    logo: "./images/account.svg",
    new: true,
    featured: false,
    position: "Junior Frontend Developer",
    role: "Frontend",
    level: "Junior",
    postedAt: "2d ago",
    contract: "Part Time",
    location: "USA Only",
    languages: ["JavaScript"],
    tools: ["React", "Sass"]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    company: "MyHome",
    logo: "./images/myhome.svg",
    new: false,
    featured: false,
    position: "Junior Frontend Developer",
    role: "Frontend",
    level: "Junior",
    postedAt: "5d ago",
    contract: "Contract",
    location: "USA Only",
    languages: ["CSS", "JavaScript"]
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    company: "Loop Studios",
    logo: "./images/loop-studios.svg",
    new: false,
    featured: false,
    position: "Software Engineer",
    role: "FullStack",
    level: "Midweight",
    postedAt: "1w ago",
    contract: "Full Time",
    location: "Worldwide",
    languages: ["JavaScript"],
    tools: ["Ruby", "Sass"]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    company: "FaceIt",
    logo: "./images/faceit.svg",
    new: false,
    featured: false,
    position: "Junior Backend Developer",
    role: "Backend",
    level: "Junior",
    postedAt: "2w ago",
    contract: "Full Time",
    location: "UK Only",
    tools: ["RoR"]
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    company: "Shortly",
    logo: "./images/shortly.svg",
    new: false,
    featured: false,
    position: "Junior Developer",
    role: "Frontend",
    level: "Junior",
    postedAt: "2w ago",
    contract: "Full Time",
    location: "Worldwide",
    languages: ["HTML", "JavaScript"],
    tools: ["Sass"]
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    company: "Insure",
    logo: "./images/insure.svg",
    new: false,
    featured: false,
    position: "Junior Frontend Developer",
    role: "Frontend",
    level: "Junior",
    postedAt: "2w ago",
    contract: "Full Time",
    location: "USA Only",
    languages: ["JavaScript"],
    tools: ["Vue, Sass"]
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    company: "Eyecam Co.",
    logo: "./images/eyecam-co.svg",
    new: false,
    featured: false,
    position: "Full Stack Engineer",
    role: "Fullstack",
    level: "Midweight",
    postedAt: "3w ago",
    contract: "Full Time",
    location: "Worldwide",
    languages: ["JavaScript", "Python"],
    tools: ["Django"]
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    company: "The Air Filter Company",
    logo: "./images/the-air-filter-company.svg",
    new: false,
    featured: false,
    position: "Front-end Dev",
    role: "Frontend",
    level: "Junior",
    postedAt: "1mo ago",
    contract: "Part Time",
    location: "Worldwide",
    languages: ["JavaScript"],
    tools: ["React", "Sass"]
  }
];

// const filters =  ['Python']

// const arrayOfTags = data.map(item => [item.level, item.role].concat(item.tools,item.languages))
// let filteredArr = arrayOfTags.forEach((tag,i) => {
//     filters.forEach((filter,j) => {

//     })
// })
// console.log(filteredArr)
```

I'm working on a list with filtering feature.

I need to filter the array of objects based on the tags.

Take a look here -> https://codepen.io/AdamKniec/pen/BaoJvWK
or at the SO code snippet

I need to return those objects that contain the tags specified in the `filters` array.

Only values from the below Object's key's can be a tag.

-role

-tools

-level

-languages

I tried to implement it (commented section in the codepen example) but I failed. Could You guys please help me to implement that ? How can I achieve that with ES6 array methods ?
Thank in advance. If more clarification is required - please let me know and I will update the question :)

Comment: Transfer yourv code over to this site as a [mcve]

Comment: Stackoverflow supports inline html/css/js and it will get executed

Comment: I've just made an edit with the codeSnippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate data and then combine tags to filter. Use `.some` method, to match any of filters or `.every` method, to match all of filters.

```
const filters = ["Python", "React"];

let filteredArr = data.filter((user) => {
  const tags = [user.level, user.role].concat(user.tools, user.languages);
  return filters.every(f => tags.includes(f));
});
console.log(filteredArr);
```

> Working samples:

**Match all[AND]:**

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"company":"Photosnap","logo":"./images/photosnap.svg","new":true,"featured":true,"position":"Senior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Senior","postedAt":"1d ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["HTML","CSS","JavaScript"]},{"id":2,"company":"Manage","logo":"./images/manage.svg","new":true,"featured":true,"position":"Fullstack Developer","role":"Fullstack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"1d ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"Remote","languages":["Python"],"tools":["React"]},{"id":3,"company":"Account","logo":"./images/account.svg","new":true,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2d ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["React","Sass"]},{"id":4,"company":"MyHome","logo":"./images/myhome.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"5d ago","contract":"Contract","location":"USA Only","languages":["CSS","JavaScript"]},{"id":5,"company":"Loop Studios","logo":"./images/loop-studios.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Software Engineer","role":"FullStack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"1w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["Ruby","Sass"]},{"id":6,"company":"FaceIt","logo":"./images/faceit.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Backend Developer","role":"Backend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"UK Only","tools":["RoR"]},{"id":7,"company":"Shortly","logo":"./images/shortly.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["HTML","JavaScript"],"tools":["Sass"]},{"id":8,"company":"Insure","logo":"./images/insure.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["Vue, Sass"]},{"id":9,"company":"Eyecam Co.","logo":"./images/eyecam-co.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Full Stack Engineer","role":"Fullstack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"3w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript","Python"],"tools":["Django"]},{"id":10,"company":"The Air Filter Company","logo":"./images/the-air-filter-company.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Front-end Dev","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"1mo ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["React","Sass"]}]
const filters = ["Python", "React"];

let filteredArr = data.filter((user) => {
  const tags = [user.level, user.role].concat(user.tools, user.languages);
  return filters.every(f => tags.includes(f));
});
console.log(filteredArr);
```

**Match any[OR]:**

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"company":"Photosnap","logo":"./images/photosnap.svg","new":true,"featured":true,"position":"Senior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Senior","postedAt":"1d ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["HTML","CSS","JavaScript"]},{"id":2,"company":"Manage","logo":"./images/manage.svg","new":true,"featured":true,"position":"Fullstack Developer","role":"Fullstack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"1d ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"Remote","languages":["Python"],"tools":["React"]},{"id":3,"company":"Account","logo":"./images/account.svg","new":true,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2d ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["React","Sass"]},{"id":4,"company":"MyHome","logo":"./images/myhome.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"5d ago","contract":"Contract","location":"USA Only","languages":["CSS","JavaScript"]},{"id":5,"company":"Loop Studios","logo":"./images/loop-studios.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Software Engineer","role":"FullStack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"1w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["Ruby","Sass"]},{"id":6,"company":"FaceIt","logo":"./images/faceit.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Backend Developer","role":"Backend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"UK Only","tools":["RoR"]},{"id":7,"company":"Shortly","logo":"./images/shortly.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["HTML","JavaScript"],"tools":["Sass"]},{"id":8,"company":"Insure","logo":"./images/insure.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["Vue, Sass"]},{"id":9,"company":"Eyecam Co.","logo":"./images/eyecam-co.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Full Stack Engineer","role":"Fullstack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"3w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript","Python"],"tools":["Django"]},{"id":10,"company":"The Air Filter Company","logo":"./images/the-air-filter-company.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Front-end Dev","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"1mo ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["React","Sass"]}]
const filters = ["Python", "React"];

let filteredArr = data.filter((user) => {
  const tags = [user.level, user.role].concat(user.tools, user.languages);
  return filters.some(f => tags.includes(f));
});
console.log(filteredArr);
```

**More complex filter:**

```
const filters = {
  role: "Frontend",
  level: "Junior",
  tags: ["Python", "React"],
};
```

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"company":"Photosnap","logo":"./images/photosnap.svg","new":true,"featured":true,"position":"Senior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Senior","postedAt":"1d ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["HTML","CSS","JavaScript"]},{"id":2,"company":"Manage","logo":"./images/manage.svg","new":true,"featured":true,"position":"Fullstack Developer","role":"Fullstack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"1d ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"Remote","languages":["Python"],"tools":["React"]},{"id":3,"company":"Account","logo":"./images/account.svg","new":true,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2d ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["React","Sass"]},{"id":4,"company":"MyHome","logo":"./images/myhome.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"5d ago","contract":"Contract","location":"USA Only","languages":["CSS","JavaScript"]},{"id":5,"company":"Loop Studios","logo":"./images/loop-studios.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Software Engineer","role":"FullStack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"1w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["Ruby","Sass"]},{"id":6,"company":"FaceIt","logo":"./images/faceit.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Backend Developer","role":"Backend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"UK Only","tools":["RoR"]},{"id":7,"company":"Shortly","logo":"./images/shortly.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["HTML","JavaScript"],"tools":["Sass"]},{"id":8,"company":"Insure","logo":"./images/insure.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Junior Frontend Developer","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"2w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"USA Only","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["Vue, Sass"]},{"id":9,"company":"Eyecam Co.","logo":"./images/eyecam-co.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Full Stack Engineer","role":"Fullstack","level":"Midweight","postedAt":"3w ago","contract":"Full Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript","Python"],"tools":["Django"]},{"id":10,"company":"The Air Filter Company","logo":"./images/the-air-filter-company.svg","new":false,"featured":false,"position":"Front-end Dev","role":"Frontend","level":"Junior","postedAt":"1mo ago","contract":"Part Time","location":"Worldwide","languages":["JavaScript"],"tools":["React","Sass"]}]

const filters = {
  role: "Frontend",
  level: "Junior",
  tags: ["Python", "React"],
};

let filteredArr = data.filter((user) => {
  const tools = (user.tools || []).concat(user.languages);
  return Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      return user[key] == value;
    } else {
      return value.some((f) => tools.includes(f));
    }
  });
});
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Array method `filter()` to limit the array of peoples.

To filter by one parameter you could use `includes()` but you are using array of filters so `.every()` is a better option (it behaves like AND), you could also use `.some()` to find person with at least one language.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    languages: ["HTML", "JavaScript"],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    languages: ["JavaScript"],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    languages: ["JavaScript", "Python"],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    languages: ["JavaScript"],
  }
];

const filters =  ['JavaScript']

const filterByLanguage = ( list, filters ) => {
  return list.filter( person => filters.every( filter => person.languages.includes(filter) ))
}

console.log('JS')
console.log( filterByLanguage(data, ['JavaScript'] ) )

console.log('JS + Python')
console.log( filterByLanguage(data, ['JavaScript', 'Python'] ) )
```

You can expand those filters like this:

```
list.filter( person => {
  const haveAllLanguages = filters.every( filter => person.languages.includes(filter) )
  return  haveAllLanguages && person.age > 18
}
))
```

You have to return true for filter() to add it to the response.